# Python 3 print UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, unicode

How can I print `’` (unicode u2019) in python exactly as `’`? Note: I know that if I do `print(text_bytes)` that I get `b'’'`, this is not what i want, just `’`. Using python version 3.5.3 on Windows 10.

Code:

```
text = '’'
text_bytes = text.encode('utf-8')
text_str = str(text_bytes, 'utf-8')
print(text_str)
```

Result:

```
File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: This code works for me (Python v3.6.3).

Comment: `text = '’'` and `print(text)` works for me, using cpython 3.7.0 on win7. Copy-pasted the output line into http://unicode.scarfboy.com/ to verify that it was indeed u+2019 and not a different identical-looking character. Why do you need to byte-encode it and back?
edit: your example code also works properly for me as well

Comment: Yeah I was surprised it wasn't working. Think it's my libraries then? Using version 3.5.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: See the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/5320906) on the possible dupe question.